# Set array as object property JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using [Rajeshwar Patlolla](https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-datepicker) datepicker and the disabledDates property receives an array of Dates().

Can I set an array as a object property? Something like this:
[image]

$scope.datasFormatoCorreto has an array of dates that I get from a json:
[image]

Comment: yes, have you tried `disabledDates: $scope.datasFormatoCorreto` unless I am misunderstanding your question.

Answer (score 0):

It was a stupid error....

As Damon says, disabledDates: $scope.datasFormatoCorreto it's correct. I was trying disabledDates: **[**$scope.datasFormatoCorreto**]**

Thanks, Damon!